# Using token in Block title

Tags: 7, blocks, tokens

I want to use token to show user name in block title. But it is not working.
I tried like [user:name]

Thanks in advacne

Comment: By default, tokens are not available in blocks. Why do you think you could use them?

Comment: Here is the list of all token:https://www.drupal.org/node/390482#token-current-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct format is `[current-user:name]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `[site:current-user]` to get current username.